# How to get Visual studio to load and trig breakpoints using chrome instead of Explorer

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging

When debugging a web project using visual studio by attaching to the process we can trigger breakpoints in the code (C#.net server side code, not javascript) and inspect it.

This however only works if the browser doing the request is explorer. When using chrome visual studio only shows the warning about the breakpoint not getting hit  because of unloaded symbols.

How do we trigger the debug-loading in visual studio from another browser.

Comment: Programming-related questions should be posted on [so]. I have voted for this to be migrated. Also, please specify the specific version of Visual Studio you are interested in answers for.

Comment: Given you're debugging on the IIS process, it's likely to be the server reacting differently. So a first thing to try is to use the User Agent Switcher extension to have Chrome report itself as IE. Another would be to sniff the traffic to IIS to see what, if anything, it's doing differently.

Comment: Yes obviously the server is reacting differently. The question is why it would do that. My hope would be that someone could confirm that it's indeed the User agent header or another special header IE uses that triggers the debugging to work. I will try out those things in the days and see what if anything chanes it.